# C char pointer vs pointer to char array, increment dynamic allocation

Tags: c

I am new to C, and I am having difficulty understanding the reason why the block of code below is not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *src = "http://localhost";

    /* THIS WORKS
       char scheme[10];
       char *dp = scheme;
     */

    //DOESN'T WORK
    char *dp = malloc(10);

    while (*src != ':') {
        *dp = *src;
        src++;
        dp++;
    }
    *dp = '\0';

    /* WORKS
       puts(scheme)
     */

    //DOESN'T WORK
    puts(dp);
}
```

The expected output is `http` to stdout. In both cases `dp` should be a pointer to an array of char pointers `(char **)`. However it is printing nothing when using `malloc` method. I ran the code through GDB and my `src` and `dp` are getting erased 1 character at a time. If I enclose the `while` loop into a function call it works. I figured that the reason was because parameters are evaluated as a copy. However, then I read that arrays are the exception and passed as pointers. Now I am confused. I can work around this, but I am trying to understand why this way doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are changing `dp` inside the loop

```
dp = malloc(10);
```

let's say `dp` has the value `0x42000000`

```
while () {
    dp++;
}
```

let's say the loop went 4 times, so `dp` has the value `0x42000004`

```
*dp = 0;
```

now you put a null character at the address pointed to by `dp`

```
puts(dp);
```

and then you try to print that null :)

Save `dp` and print the saved value

```
dp = malloc(10);
saveddp = dp;
/* ... */
puts(saveddp);
free(saveddp); /* for completeness */
```

---

It works with `scheme` because `scheme` is an array and you cannot change that address!

Answer (score 4):

After the end of the loop, `dp` points to the end of the allocated string. You need to save `dp` right after the `malloc` and increment the copy, not the original pointer to the beginning.

Comment: And maybe declare it as `char *const dp = malloc(10);` so the compiler won't let you make this mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Before the loop starts the `dp` points to the start of the memory you have allocated. At each iteration you copy the character pointed by `src` into the currently pointed location of `dp` and step forward one memory location pointed by `dp`. At the end of the loop `dp` is pointing at the memory location right after the character `p` where you have assigned a `'\0'`. When you attempt to print the string with `puts (dp)` because the contents of `dp` has changed and now points to a location right *after the last character copied*, it will start printing from that location. It will print an empty string as the very first location pointed by `dp` is a null character.

#### Before Loop

```
+----------+
|   src    |
+----------+
   |
   | 
   V
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----       ----+----+
|  h  |  t  |  t  |  p  |  :  |  /  |  /  |     . . .   ? |  ? |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----       ----+----+

+----------+
|    dp    |
+----------+
   |
   | 
   V
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----       ----+----+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     . . .     |    |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----       ----+----+
```

#### After Loop (with dp = malloc (10))

```
                      +----------+
                      |   src    |
                      +----------+
                           |
                           | 
                           V
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----       ----+----+
|  h  |  t  |  t  |  p  |  :  |  /  |  /  |     . . .     |  ? |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----       ----+----+

                      +----------+
                      |    dp    |
                      +----------+
                           |
                           | 
                           V
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----       ----+----+
|  h  |  t  |  t  |  p  |  \0 |     |     |     . . .     |    |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----       ----+----+
```

Note `puts (dp)` will start printing print from the location pointed above.
This will not get the intended output. Also because you have not saved the
original address of `dp` which you have actually allocated. You are not able
to restore it after the loop.

#### After Loop (with dp = &scheme)

```
                      +----------+
                      |   src    |
                      +----------+
                           |
                           | 
                           V
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----       ----+----+
|  h  |  t  |  t  |  p  |  :  |  /  |  /  |     . . .     |  ? |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----       ----+----+

                              +----------+
                              |    dp    |
                              +----------+
                                   |
                                   | 
                                   V
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----       ----+----+
scheme[ |  h  |  t  |  t  |  p  |  \0 |     |     |     . . .     |    | ]
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----       ----+----+

puts (scheme) will work because it still refers to the base of the array
puts (dp) will not work because it does not point to the base of the array
         and currently points to a location pointing to null character
```

In the above commented solution of yours works because, you use the `scheme` array to print the string. `scheme` refers to the array you want to print and `scheme` refers to the base address of the array because you have not modified it (and it cannot be modified). This is why it starts from the base and prints upto the `'\0'` you have assigned after the loop.

You can either do

```
 int i;
 for (i=0; (src[i] != ':') && (src[i] != '\0'); i++)
 {
    dp[i] = src[i];
 }
```

or do the below

```
 char *dp_bak;
 char *dp = malloc(10);
 dp_bak = dp; /* Backup the base address */

 while (*src != ':')
 {
     *dp = *src;
     src++;
     dp++;
 }
 *dp = '\0';
 dp = db_bak; /* Restore the base address */

 puts (dp);
```

Answer (score -2):

Indeed, as pointed out above, "scheme" was your pointer to the beginning of the string, and dp was your iterator.

char *scheme = malloc(10), *dp = scheme;

...

puts(scheme);